# error starting gravity servlet in tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, tomcat7, graniteds

I setup graniteds and gravity servlet in java spring application that runs in tomcat 7.
in web xml :

```
<servlet-class>org.granite.gravity.servlet3.GravityAsyncServlet</servlet-class>
```

and an AMF meswage servlet class :

```
<servlet-class>org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFMessageServlet</servlet-class>
```

and a graniteConfig classe that is read by tomcat servlet :

```
@ServerFilter
public class GraniteConfig
```

the amf messaging works well . but the gravity servlet could not start correctly . i debugged graniteds libraries .
this line of code won't pass

```
ServletGraniteConfig servletGraniteConfig = (ServletGraniteConfig)context.getAttribute(GRANITE_CONFIG_KEY);
```

(this code is from graniteDs Core librairies) and the error was :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.granite.config.GraniteConfig cannot be cast to org.granite.config.ServletGraniteConfig
```

i don't get how the graniteConfig object is set in servletContext attributes instead of ServletGraniteConfig .
and what part of graniteds configuration i'm missing .

Comment: This smells like a classloader problem, as in one class is loaded in classloader A and the other class is loaded in classloader B. That tends to be caused by duplicate jars, such as there being jars in tomcat/lib and in the web application's lib folder. The code regarding this does not provide any hint as to how it could otherwise be a problem: http://www.granitedataservices.com/public/doc/2.1.0/doc/java/api/src-html/org/granite/config/ServletGraniteConfig.html

Comment: Yup , i think that this is the broblem . i didn't 100% debugged but this solved the problem : in pom.xml i updated the version of graniteds from 3.1.0.GA to 3.1.0.RC1(the latest) and i deleted a maven dependencie (<artifactId>granite-gravity</artifactId>) . I guess this dependecies contains duplicate classes in other ortifacts  as you said .

Comment: That's a downgrade. GA = general availability (AKA: final), RC1 = Release Candidate 1 (AKA: beta). You did not at all understood what I was saying and have nto solved your problem, you merely made it go away by just trying some stuff. That's fine, but I expect you and your problem to return at one point in time.

Comment: ok @Gimby . In my defense that's how coder behave under pressure deadline . I will try to have accurate anwers when i have time . thanks  :)